# Construct a tree using arraycollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

How can we construct like lynda course structure in flex using tree which having data provider a array collection ? Inside array collection i have two arrays also. I need the structure as per the lynda course preview. Can anyone help me out ? Please Refer the lynda course structure.

Refer the link -- http://www.lynda.com/Photoshop-tutorials/Design-Web-Getting-CSS-from-Photoshop/151161-2.html

Just like the screens shot

[image]

Comment: Generically; use a Tree or AdvancedDataGrid.  What have you tried and why didn't it work?  Can you share code?

Comment: I agree with Reboog711, there are components that have the functionality and appropriate management for these cases.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at this Link and read again & again your text item! yet fail to understand where the Array comes in ??? this looks to me quiet plain sailing you would just have to decide what you like! I use Thumbnail tree set ups as well as normal Tree set ups as well as Linked module Tree set ups where as the last would I assume be the bet for you!
YES, I did recheck that again so here is one of many I use to view in action.

Please go to [enter link description here](http://www.uppercut-spottheartography.webflashartistry.com/) select the Tab two(2)=Show Case & once you have closed the pop Up window select the Directory item (Featured Artists - EXAMPLE) that will open the Tree node just like in the Linda example and so on!
This Tree works with modules so selects different .swf file modules showing video, text, anything really independently as you can test for yourself by selecting Information, Img. Gallery etc.! I hope this will help and if code is required please let me know! regards aktell for WebFlashArtistry@gmail.com

Comment: @aktell... Thanks for your intrest. Yes of course i want the code.Can you help me out.

Comment: Hi again, its to late today as I'm in New Zealand write an E-mail as above so that I can send it once I have compiled it for you! regards aktell

Comment: if you have completed then you can send me the code to parichhahimansu@gmail.com